# Finding an Analytical Relationship Between Variables

Tags: matlab, fitting

I have a spreadsheet read from a metheorological system with a simple model embedded. I solved the most variables by simple inspection and through related literature, but unfortunately, the literature of the physical process is being *very* obscure on this specific variable, and the person who programmed it is no longer available.

I know my main variable $y$ depends on some others $x_i$ in the form $y=f(x_1...x_{22})$.

$f(\cdot)$ should be a simple relationship including a few composition of products $x_ix_j$, powers $x_i^\alpha$ exponentiation $x_i^{x_j}$ and linear functions $\alpha x_i+\beta$. No sines, cosines or any other kind of real functions.

For an initial dataset, I found the relation to be

$$y=0.3229(x_{3}+6.4103){100-x_{16} \over 100}, R^2=0.9994$$

But testing with a second dataset this relation got broken, so should be something related to that, perhaps including some additional term somewhere.

Do somebody know a numerical solver for this kind problem, or how should i proceed?

The initial and testing datasets are in this link I just uploaded:
http://www.filedropper.com/datasets

Comment: Have you considered using a support vector machine? These types of compositions (xixj, etc.) resemble non-linearities that are addressed by kernels in SVM.

Comment: I am just trying to find the original expression used by the programmer in the original model. I guessed all of them except this last one. it should be a simple one.

Comment: I see. The simplest solution I can think of is an exhaustive search. 
Alternatively, have a look at the paper on Generalized PCA (https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1202/1202.4002.pdf). It addresses a simple version of your problem. See if it's worth your time to apply. There's probably a matlab implementation for it available online.

Comment: I knew this paper from some time ago. I fear this do not solve my problem... Thanks for the document.